# TextboxFor element and CheckboxFor element are null and not sent to POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, summernote

I have a weird situation where we have this view model:

```
public class AddCommunicationViewModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid ParentCommunicationGroupId { get; set; }
        public Guid ParentCommunicationGroupCampaignId { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> CommunicationTypes { get; set; } 
        public CommunicationType SelectedCommunicationTypeId { get; set; }

        [AllowHtml]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [AllowHtml]
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Reference { get; set; }
        public bool AttachDemand { get; set; }
        public int CommunicationSortingIndex { get; set; }
        public string CommunicationGroupName { get; set; }


        public AddCommunicationViewModel()
        {
            CommunicationTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
    }
```

Now, I have a very simple form (using `Html.BeginForm`) which posts to the controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateSavedCommunication", "Communication", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "saveCommunication" }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.ParentCommunicationGroupCampaignId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.ParentCommunicationGroupId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Id)


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.SelectedCommunicationTypeId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.SelectedCommunicationTypeId, Model.CommunicationTypes, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="div_subject form-group email">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Subject)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Subject, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="div_content form-group mb-3">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Content)
        <div class="card-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <textarea name="Content" id="summernote" class="summernote" data-plugin-summernote data-plugin-options='{ "height": 280, "codemirror": { "theme": "ambiance" } }'>
                            @Html.Raw(Model.Content)
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div_reference form-group email">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Reference)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Reference, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>


    <div class="div_attachdemand form-group mb-3">
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(c => c.AttachDemand)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.AttachDemand)
        </div>
    </div>


    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Gem" onclick="document.getElementById('saveCommunication').submit();" />
}
```

The reason my "Content" variable is a bit weird, is because I user the Summernote editor. When I click the submit button all posts fine without any JavaScript errors.

However, now the weird stuff comes.

My variables: `Reference` and `AttachDemand` is NOT posted to server. Looking at Fiddler, I can see this is the post:

```
ParentCommunicationGroupCampaignId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&ParentCommunicationGroupId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&Id=2953bc1b-49e5-4f65-8159-1c53de5c82e8&SelectedCommunicationTypeId=2&Subject=&Content=++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%3Cp%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%280%2C+0%2C+0%29%3B%22%3EHej%C2%A0*%7CNAME%7C*.%C2%A0%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%280%2C+0%2C+0%29%3B%22%3E*%7CCREDITORNAME%7C*+har+bedt+os+inddrive+din+g%C3%A6ld+hos+dem.+Der+er+tale+om+en+g%C3%A6ld+p%C3%A5%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%280%2C+0%2C+0%29%3B%22%3E%C2%A0%3C%2Fspan%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%280%2C+0%2C+0%29%3B%22%3E*%7CDEMANDLINK%7C*+kr%2C+som+du+bedes+betale.%3Cbr%3EVi+har+vedh%C3%A6ftet+kravet+i+dette+brev+p%C3%A5+e-mail.%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%280%2C+0%2C+0%29%3B%22%3EDet+er+vigtigt+at+du+betales+denne+g%C3%A6ld+hurtigst+muligt%2C+for+at+undg%C3%A5+at+der+p%C3%A5l%C3%B8ber+ekstra+renter+samt+en+registrering+hos+RKI+og+som+videre+konsekvens+sendt+til+fogedretten.%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%280%2C+0%2C+0%29%3B%22%3ESE+DIN+SAG+OG+BETAL%3A+*%7CDEMANDLINK%7C*%C2%A0%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%280%2C+0%2C+0%29%3B%22%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cspan+style%3D%22color%3A+rgb%280%2C+0%2C+0%29%3B%22%3EVh%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fspan%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++&files=
```

Or in a view for humans:

[image]

So my challenge is: where is my `Reference` and `AttachDemand` ?

Now, if I move these two ABOVE the content editor, they work. So it seems that the `Content` is breaking because it sends some pretty cool HTML.

So any idea how to "make" this work? I guess I need to somehow escape the input in some smart way? I have added `[AllowHtml]` on the content attribute because it will contain HTML, but more than that?

Comment: You have nested forms which is invalid html and not supported

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you mark it as an answer? :-) That's of course the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view has nested forms which is invalid html and not supported (and depending on the browser and version, you may see different results).

Remove the inner `<form class="form-horizontal form-bordered">` surrounding the textarea to ensure all from controls are serialized and sent in the request.